# Using checkbox filtering data in datagrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, fms3

on selecting  a checkbox data in datagrid must filter and on deselecting checkbox the  default data in datagrid  must appear .

Comment: Hie Abhinav and Brain Bishop. I have  created   6 coloumns under 3 categories , and used a filter fucntion to filter the data. the problem is  the data specified to a category is filtered and when  two check boxes of different categories are selected  filter function is not working fine .

Comment: Could you provide some data for test purposes? Or at least a screenshot of the filled DG? Please don't post your code and other stuff as an answer. Instead edit your initial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just an issue of logic.

You should not mix the intermediate results of the three groups by means of disjunction. At first you should do disjunction inside of each factor and then conjunction of the three intermediate results.

If one of three factors has no selected variants it may not have an impact on the overall result, so you need to set the initial values to true.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
            layout="absolute" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="init()">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        [Bindable]public var DGcoll:ArrayCollection;
        private var DGarray:Array;

        private function init():void
        {
            DGarray = [
                {Gametype: '101P00l',   Bet: 500,   MaxPlayers:2, TotalPlayers:2, Status:"ok", RegTable:"rt"}, 
                {Gametype: '201P00l',   Bet: 1000,  MaxPlayers:6, TotalPlayers:5, Status:"ok", RegTable:"rt"},
                {Gametype: '201P00l',   Bet: 500,   MaxPlayers:2, TotalPlayers:2, Status:"ok", RegTable:"rt"},
                {Gametype: '101P00l',   Bet: 4000,  MaxPlayers:6, TotalPlayers:3, Status:"ok", RegTable:"rt"},
                {Gametype: 'Bestof3',   Bet: 5000,  MaxPlayers:6, TotalPlayers:2, Status:"ok", RegTable:"rt"},
                {Gametype: 'Bestof3',   Bet: 4000,  MaxPlayers:6, TotalPlayers:6, Status:"ok", RegTable:"rt"},
                {Gametype: '201P00l',   Bet: 500,   MaxPlayers:2, TotalPlayers:2, Status:"ok", RegTable:"rt"},
                {Gametype: '201P00l',   Bet: 500,   MaxPlayers:2, TotalPlayers:2, Status:"ok", RegTable:"rt"},
                {Gametype: '201P00l',   Bet: 500,   MaxPlayers:2, TotalPlayers:2, Status:"ok", RegTable:"rt"},
                {Gametype: '201P00l',   Bet: 500,   MaxPlayers:2, TotalPlayers:2, Status:"ok", RegTable:"rt"}
            ];

            addData();
        }

        public function addData():void
        {
            DGcoll = new ArrayCollection(DGarray);
            DGcoll.filterFunction=filterFunction;
        }

        public function filterFunction(item:Object):Boolean
        {
            if (checkAll.selected)
                return true;

            if(check101 && check201 && check3 && check2players && check6players && checklow && checkmedium && checkhigh)
            {
                if(!check101.selected && !check201.selected && !check3.selected && !check2players.selected && !check6players.selected && !checklow.selected && !checkmedium.selected && !checkhigh.selected)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    var gametypeFactor:Boolean = true;

                    if (check101.selected || check201.selected || check3.selected)
                    {
                        var Fcheck101:Boolean =check101.selected ? item.Gametype == '101P00l' : false;
                        var Fcheck201:Boolean =check201.selected ? item.Gametype == '201P00l' : false;
                        var Fcheck3:Boolean =check3.selected ? item.Gametype == 'Bestof3' : false;

                        gametypeFactor = Fcheck101 || Fcheck201 || Fcheck3;
                    }

                    var maxPlayersFactor:Boolean = true;

                    if (check2players.selected || check6players.selected)
                    {
                        var Fcheck2players:Boolean=check2players.selected ?item.MaxPlayers=='2':false;
                        var Fcheck6players:Boolean=check6players.selected ?item.MaxPlayers=='6':false;

                        maxPlayersFactor = Fcheck2players || Fcheck6players;
                    }

                    var betFactor:Boolean = true;

                    if (checklow.selected || checkmedium.selected || checkhigh.selected)
                    {
                        var Fchecklow1:Boolean=checklow.selected ?item.Bet=='500':false;
                        var Fchecklow2:Boolean=checklow.selected ?item.Bet=='1000':false;

                        var Fcheckmedium1:Boolean=checkmedium.selected ?item.Bet=='1000':false;
                        var Fcheckmedium2:Boolean=checkmedium.selected ?item.Bet=='2000':false;
                        var Fcheckmedium3:Boolean=checkmedium.selected ?item.Bet=='3000':false;

                        var Fcheckhigh1:Boolean=checkhigh.selected ?item.Bet=='3000':false;
                        var Fcheckhigh2:Boolean=checkhigh.selected ?item.Bet=='4000':false;
                        var Fcheckhigh3:Boolean=checkhigh.selected ?item.Bet=='5000':false;
                        var Fcheckhigh4:Boolean=checkhigh.selected ?item.Bet=='10000':false;

                        betFactor = Fchecklow1 || Fchecklow2 || Fcheckmedium1 ||Fcheckmedium2 ||Fcheckmedium3 || Fcheckhigh1 || Fcheckhigh2 || Fcheckhigh3 || Fcheckhigh4;
                    }

                    return gametypeFactor && maxPlayersFactor && betFactor;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                return true;   
            } 
        }

        private function onCbAllClick(evt:Event):void
        {
            check101.enabled = !checkAll.selected;
            check201.enabled = !checkAll.selected;
            check3.enabled = !checkAll.selected;
            check2players.enabled = !checkAll.selected;
            check6players.enabled = !checkAll.selected;
            checklow.enabled = !checkAll.selected;
            checkmedium.enabled = !checkAll.selected;
            checkhigh.enabled = !checkAll.selected;

            DGcoll.refresh();
        }

        private function onAnyCbClick(evt:Event):void
        {
            DGcoll.refresh();
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:Canvas width="648" height="347" x="162" y="40">

    <mx:HBox x="30">
        <mx:Label text="Show all infos" fontSize="12"/>
        <mx:CheckBox id="checkAll" click="onCbAllClick(event)"/>
    </mx:HBox>

    <mx:Label x="95" y="21" text="Gametype" fontSize="12" width="140"/>
    <mx:Label x="311" y="21" text="Players" fontSize="12" width="98"/>
    <mx:Label x="468" y="21" text="Bet" fontSize="12" width="123"/>
    <mx:HBox height="47" y="49" width="608" x="30">
        <mx:CheckBox id="check101"  x="30" y="48" click="onAnyCbClick(event)" />
        <mx:Label text="101Pool" x="42" y="48"/>
        <mx:CheckBox id="check201"  x="67" y="48" click="onAnyCbClick(event)" />
        <mx:Label  text="201pool" x="79" y="48"/>
        <mx:CheckBox id="check3"  x="125" y="48" click="onAnyCbClick(event)"/>
        <mx:Label text=" Bestof3" x="147" y="48"/>
        <mx:CheckBox id="check2players"  x="214" y="48" click="onAnyCbClick(event)"/>
        <mx:Label text="2 Players" x="228" y="48"/>
        <mx:CheckBox id="check6players"  x="292" y="48" click="onAnyCbClick(event)"/>
        <mx:Label text="6 Players" x="307" y="48"/>
        <mx:CheckBox id="checklow"  x="371" y="48" click="onAnyCbClick(event)"/>
        <mx:Label text="Low" x="393" y="48"/>
        <mx:CheckBox id="checkmedium"  x="421" y="48" click="DGcoll.refresh();"/>
        <mx:Label text="Medium" x="443" y="48"/>
        <mx:CheckBox id="checkhigh" x="498" y="48" click="onAnyCbClick(event)"/>
        <mx:Label text="High" x="520" y="48"/>
    </mx:HBox>
    <mx:DataGrid  id="dg"  dataProvider="{DGcoll}" sortArrowSkin="mx.skins.ProgrammaticSkin" x="30" y="104" width="608" height="217">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Gametype"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Bet"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="MaxPlayers"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="TotalPlayers"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Status"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="RegTable"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
</mx:Canvas>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Hello @Anton  now if i have to add an checkbox with name all. On selection which displays all the information present in the datagrid without any consideration of  other checkboxes selection.How could i do that.                                                       Thanks in Advance

Comment: I would just add a new condition to the filterFunction [if (checkAll.selected) return true;] And it can be important to disable all other check boxes to show the user that there is no filter condition in the moment. I have updated my code to show you what I mean.

Comment: The code work's fine.Thank you Very much @Anton for spending your valuable time to solve my problem .

Comment: if I click the button Present in datagrid  it lods an module and  now my problem is when i click the button in a row the datagrid selection remains  same but the datagrid is refreshed which is not correct working of filter function if  we click a button the selection must remains same as it is before clicking the button ,which is clicked to load a module.

Comment: Could you explain this matter with the button? What should be done? May be you can post a new version of code to let me understand the new functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
        [Bindable] 
        public var DGcoll:ArrayCollection;

        public function addData():void
        {
            DGcoll=new ArrayCollection(DGarray);
            DGcoll.filterFunction=filterFunction;
             trace(filterFunction(DGcoll)); 
        }

        public function filterFunction(item:Object):Boolean
        {

            if(check101 && check201 && check3 && check2players && check6players && checklow && checkmedium && checkhigh)
            {
                if(!check101.selected && !check201.selected && !check3.selected && !check2players.selected && !check6players.selected && !checklow.selected && !checkmedium.selected && !checkhigh.selected)
                {
                return true;
                }
                else
                {
                        trace(" if filterfunction");
                var Fcheck101:Boolean =check101.selected ? item.Gametype == '101P00l' : false;
                var Fcheck201:Boolean =check201.selected ? item.Gametype == '201P00l' : false;
                var Fcheck3:Boolean =check3.selected ? item.Gametype == 'Bestof3' : false;
                var Fcheck2players:Boolean=check2players.selected ?item.MaxPlayers=='2':false;
                var Fcheck6players:Boolean=check6players.selected ?item.MaxPlayers=='6':false;
                var Fchecklow1:Boolean=checklow.selected ?item.Bet=='500':false;
                var Fchecklow2:Boolean=checklow.selected ?item.Bet=='1000':false;
                var Fcheckmedium1:Boolean=checkmedium.selected ?item.Bet=='1000':false;
                var Fcheckmedium2:Boolean=checkmedium.selected ?item.Bet=='2000':false;
                var Fcheckmedium3:Boolean=checkmedium.selected ?item.Bet=='3000':false;
                var Fcheckhigh1:Boolean=checkhigh.selected ?item.Bet=='3000':false;
                var Fcheckhigh2:Boolean=checkhigh.selected ?item.Bet=='4000':false;
                var Fcheckhigh3:Boolean=checkhigh.selected ?item.Bet=='5000':false;
                var Fcheckhigh4:Boolean=checkhigh.selected ?item.Bet=='10000':false;

                return Fcheck101 || Fcheck201 || Fcheck3 || Fcheck2players || Fcheck6players ||Fchecklow1 || Fchecklow2 || Fcheckmedium1 ||Fcheckmedium2 ||Fcheckmedium3 || Fcheckhigh1 || Fcheckhigh2 || Fcheckhigh3 || Fcheckhigh4;
                }

            }
            else 
            {
                trace("else");
                return true;   
            } 

        }


    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:Canvas width="648" height="347" x="162" y="10">

    <mx:Label x="95" y="21" text="Gametype" fontSize="12" width="140"/>
    <mx:Label x="311" y="21" text="Players" fontSize="12" width="98"/>
    <mx:Label x="468" y="21" text="Bet" fontSize="12" width="123"/>
    <mx:HBox height="47" y="49" width="608" x="30">
    <mx:CheckBox id="check101"  x="30" y="48"  click="DGcoll.refresh();" />
    <mx:Label text="101Pool" x="42" y="48"/>
    <mx:CheckBox id="check201"  x="67" y="48" click="DGcoll.refresh();" />
    <mx:Label  text="201pool" x="79" y="48"/>
    <mx:CheckBox id="check3"  x="125" y="48" click="DGcoll.refresh();"/>
    <mx:Label text=" Bestof3" x="147" y="48"/>
    <mx:CheckBox id="check2players"  x="214" y="48" click="DGcoll.refresh();"/>
    <mx:Label text="2 Players" x="228" y="48"/>
    <mx:CheckBox id="check6players"  x="292" y="48" click="DGcoll.refresh();"/>
    <mx:Label text="6 Players" x="307" y="48"/>
    <mx:CheckBox id="checklow"  x="371" y="48" click="DGcoll.refresh();"/>
    <mx:Label text="Low" x="393" y="48"/>
    <mx:CheckBox id="checkmedium"  x="421" y="48" click="DGcoll.refresh();"/>
    <mx:Label text="Medium" x="443" y="48"/>
    <mx:CheckBox id="checkhigh" x="498" y="48" click="DGcoll.refresh();"/>
    <mx:Label text="High" x="520" y="48"/>
    </mx:HBox>
    <mx:DataGrid  id="dg"  dataProvider="{DGcoll}" sortArrowSkin="mx.skins.ProgrammaticSkin" x="30" y="104" width="608" height="217">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Gametype"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Bet"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="MaxPlayers"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="TotalPlayers"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Status"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="RegTable"/>
        <!--<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Join"/>-->
    </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
</mx:Canvas>
```